# Spatio-temporal cluster analysis : take accessibility into consideration

Tags: clustering, distance

I'm new in clustering topic. I have a data set with  column A : Date, B: Event (let say a number of cases of any disease) and col C and D : Lat and Long respectively. And column E, distance-time calculated from and to every single points.

Access/connectivity is very important in my analysis, since A can be closer to B than C if we consider ONLY geographical distance but closer to C if we consider accessibility (distance-time) -roads - natural barriers, etc-

I was wondering if there is any method that can take into account the distance time instead of the GPS coordinates. If so, what kind of method ? maybe just some key words to facilitate my research on the web. I'm working on R.

In my mind, I wanted to make an anamorphosis map (based on distance-time) and apply a Satscan on it. But i'm sure that this question has been aswered elsewhere yet.

Thank you in advance.